# how to change vue build.js?

Tags: web, webpack, vue.js

When I execute 'npm build' , the console show

`webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin has been removed, please use config.optimization.splitChunks instead.`,

I use vue-cli to create my project, I don't know how to change build.js . Who can help me ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused because you've upgraded from Webpack 3 to Webpack 4, which introduced some changes to the configuration API for optimizations according to this [change log](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/releases/tag/v4.0.0-beta.0)

The new API works somewhat differently, and the way webpack chunk your application is different.

Here is a default example of how `config.optimization.splitChunks` can be used in your configuration file.

```
optimization: {
    minimize: false,
    runtimeChunk: false,
    splitChunks: {
        chunks: "all",
        minSize: 30000,
        minChunks: 1,
        maxAsyncRequests: 5,
        maxInitialRequests: 3,
        automaticNameDelimiter: '-',
        name: true,
        cacheGroups: {
            default: {
                minChunks: 2,
                priority: -20,
                reuseExistingChunk: true
            },
            vendor: {
                test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                priority: -10,
                chunks: 'all'
            }
        }
    }
}
```